# HTML creating href in wrong order for rails route

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using link_to to try to delete a record, but I'm getting an error saying the delete path does not exist. When looking at the href in the html form, the href is in the form of :id/controller instead of controller/:id. I have two examples of this, one for Edit that seems to work as expected, and one for Remove, where the route seems to be off. The main difference I see is that locale is not being defined on the destroy href. Any ideas on what is causing this issue? I saw this before on a different form, but I am starting to see this much more often. Any help would be much appreciated.

Routes:

```
         topdressings GET     (/:locale)/topdressings(.:format)                             topdressings#index {:locale=>/en|es/}
                      POST    (/:locale)/topdressings(.:format)                             topdressings#create {:locale=>/en|es/}
      new_topdressing GET     (/:locale)/topdressings/new(.:format)                         topdressings#new {:locale=>/en|es/}
     edit_topdressing GET     (/:locale)/topdressings/:id/edit(.:format)                    topdressings#edit {:locale=>/en|es/}
                      GET     (/:locale)/topdressings/:id(.:format)                         topdressings#show {:locale=>/en|es/}
                      PATCH   (/:locale)/topdressings/:id(.:format)                         topdressings#update {:locale=>/en|es/}
                      PUT     (/:locale)/topdressings/:id(.:format)                         topdressings#update {:locale=>/en|es/}
                      DELETE  (/:locale)/topdressings/:id(.:format)                         topdressings#destroy {:locale=>/en|es/}
```

HTML:

```
  <td><%= link_to t(:edit), edit_topdressing_path(topdressing), data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#EditModal_#{topdressing.id}", remote: edit_topdressing_path(topdressing) + "#modal-edit-form" }, remote: true %>
|
<%= link_to t(:remove), topdressings_path(topdressing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: t(:confirm_remove_topdressing, device: "#{topdressing.topdressing_device.name}", date: "#{topdressing.date}") } %></td>
```

HREF DETAILS IN PAGE SOURCE

```
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal_1" data-remote="/en/topdressings/1/edit#modal-edit-form" data-remote="true" href="/en/topdressings/1/edit">Edit</a>
|
<a data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete the record for Device 2 on 2016-02-26" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/1/topdressings"><span>Remove</span></a></td>
```

ERROR ON DELETE:

```
Started DELETE "/1/topdressing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-05 14:34:06 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/1/topdressing"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
```

HTML FORM details:

Answer (score 0):

Your second link uses the `topdressing_path` URL helper and passes it one argument:

```
link_to t(:remove), topdressings_path(topdressing), method: :delete
```

But your `rake routes` shows that path only has one placeholder in it, for the locale:

```
     topdressings GET     (/:locale)/topdressings(.:format)
```

---

You need to use another URL helper instead. In [Rails' resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) you'd have a `topdressing_path` that you could use:

```
link_to t(:remove), topdressing_path(topdressing), method: :delete
```

But I'm guessing that's not how you've got your routes set up. Chances are, you've got something like this in `config/routes.rb`. You can add an `as` option to [give that route a name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes), allowing you to use it in your `link_to` helpers in your views:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|nl/ do
  # Other routes omitted
  get "topdressings/:id", to: "topdressings#show", as: "topdressing" 
end
```